# Is leg "falling asleep" (e.g. during meditation) dangerous?

Tags: blood-circulation, nerves, meditation, numbness

During meditation sits of 30 to 60 minutes, it is common for one or other leg to "fall asleep" after maybe 15 to 20 minutes. Is a leg being "asleep" for between 10 and 45 minutes dangerous? Is it likely to cause nerve damage or some other problem if you do this regularly?

### Prior research

Googling for "meditation leg falling asleep dangerous" returns a lot of meditation-based websites, mostly with advice on how to avoid your leg falling asleep, or advice for how to endure it psychologically, but no advice from medical sources on whether it is harmful for the stated periods of time when repeated often (e.g. daily or more, for periods of up to 45 minutes at a time).

Googling for "leg falling asleep dangerous" returns lots of information about why paresthesia occurs, but no specific information on safety of tolerating paresthesia for a stretch of time. The closest I can find is a [Slate article](https://slate.com/human-interest/2015/11/sleeping-limbs-when-your-arm-or-leg-falls-asleep-whats-really-happening.html) which says, with regards to sleeping on an arm causing parasthesia:

> But don’t worry: A few hours of nerve compression and decreased blood flow won’t make your arm fall off. But if paresthesia continues over a period of days or weeks, it can lead to lasting damage.

However, the source of this advice is not clear. (It is not a quote from a medical professional).

Another [article](https://www.businessinsider.com/what-causes-feet-and-legs-to-fall-asleep-2014-6?r=US&IR=T) says:

> Most people can move around and relieve the pressure on their nerves. But if "someone is not able to move or sedated they can have permanent nerve injury from this type of compression," says Traub.

However, this does not say anything about timescales.

Comment: I found lots of information from meditation-related websites, essentially saying "don't worry" or "see the discomfort as part of the practice". However, I did not find any information from medical sources.

Comment: @CareyGregory I have added some comments detailing prior research.

Comment: And your question doesn't say anything about the position. So, unclear what you're asking. Also, you're veering pretty close to seeking personal medical advice here with this q.

Comment: It has to be mentioned here that surgeons routinely stop blood flow to limbs for **hours** without harm. Merely **slowing** blood flow for an hour or less during a meditation should therefore be harmless.

Comment: How have you defined 'dangerous'?

Comment: Causing permanent or lasting damage.

Comment: @CareyGregory: on the other hand one can produce neurological damage with some torture/stress positions fairly quickly. (I can add references for that if you doubt it.) My point is that the details matter, so this question is probably too broad as it stands.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Also most forms of numbness in typical clinical practice aren't even caused by blood flow changes.  https://www.dartmouth.edu/~dons/part_2/chapter_13.html